# How to differentiate public methods and private methods during api testing?

Tags: .net, web-services, api, testing, public-method

Is it possible to test private methods of a web service, during api testing? If yes, how to differentiate public methods and private methods? I am using the object browser in VSTS to see the list of methods available.

---

Comment: The question is currently a bit out of context. Try to add “.net” tag to get more attention

Answer (score 1):

When you write `private` method, it means that this method will be used by public methods of your service. And when you test public methods you automaticly test private methods.

I think you should not test private methods because you should test only bahaviour (API) of library/web service, and it is enough for full coverage of work cases. But may be it will be more difficult for debug.

Also you can read **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440786/junit-java-testing-non-public-methods/440802#440802)** for same question.

**[One more thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/do-you-test-private-method)**