# Include Unit tests in the same package as the source code in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, package

I'm getting back into Java after a long stint in the Ruby world and I've got a question about JUnit tests and the source I'm testing.

If I've got a package of graphics code for my company, lets call it `com.example.graphics`, should I include my tests in that package too or should they be included in a seperate package, like `com.example.graphics.test`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440786/junit-java-testing-non-public-methods

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the same java package is fine.  It's actually necessary if you need to access package-private classes, methods, or fields.  However, the source should be logically separate:

```
src/main/com/example/graphics
src/test/com/example/graphics
```

Comment: +1, as suggested by the Maven Java Archetype standard directory layout

Comment: I suggest opening a new question rather than commenting on an 8 year old answer.  I suggest focusing on what specific problem you're having and what you've done to try to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to access private classes it is actually a question of flavor.

I sometimes even tend to create an additional test-project referenced to the product-project.
Therefore, product and test are clearly seperated.

Answer (score 1):

I personally keep all my tests in the same package, but in the test tree of [Maven](http://maven.apache.org)(which I always use for Java projects). Consider using Maven for your builds as well - it saves a lot of work on your part. It enforces a similar structure to what bkail mentions, but gives you much more than a standardized project folder layout - project lifecycle(clean, compile, package, test), plugins, etc .

Answer (score 0):

Putting tests in a separate package does tend to avoid the problem of accidentally having some method or class at package-scope that you intended clients to use.