# Junit protected method

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit3

I'm wondering about a nice way to deal with a protected method in Junit.

Assuming I want to test a class called A which has a protected member and constructor. 
I understood that in order to test the class A I should write another class called ATest which might extend TestCase ( this should be mandatory in Junit3 ). Because I want to test a protected method and because A has a protected constructor, my test class ATest should also extend the class A where that method is implemented in order to be able to create that class  and to access to the method.

could be a double inheritance from both classes a nice solution?

P.S I've already Known that in Junit 4 the inheritance from the TestCase might be avoided.

Comment: Can you explain why you would,like to extend TestCase? I think you should be able to do what you are saying and extend A to publicize its protected methods. I've dine it with NUnit and it works just fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [junit & java : testing non-public methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440786/junit-java-testing-non-public-methods)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To gain access to `A`'s protected members, you can just put `A` and `ATest` in the same package.

Comment: +1 - this is a common convention for testing both protected and package private (default) methods.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance of implementation.  You can implement multiple interfaces.

I would prefer using reflection to get at methods for testing that I don't want clients to know about.  Works for private methods, too.