# Stubbing/Mocking a private method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, white-box

I am currently testing a method `updateIssuesTable()`. this method is a private void method. Even worse, inside this method is a call to `getConnection()`, which returns a `Connection`, and is dependent on several private variables, which are dependent on an intialization method, which is of course dependent on something else.

Long story short, this line of code:
`Connection conn = getConnection();`

I don't want to execute at all, I just need a mocked Connection to continue execution. Belowe is the test method:

```
public void testUpdateIssuesTable() throws Exception {
        PatchWriterTask task = new PatchWriterTask();

        String sql = "update val_issues set PATCH_CREATION_INFO = ? where VAL_ISSUE_ID = ?";
        when(task1.getConnection()).thenReturn(conn);
        when(conn.prepareStatement(sql)).thenReturn(updateStatement);
        Whitebox.invokeMethod(task, "updateIssuesTable");
    }
```

The method I am testing is as follows:

```
    private void updateIssuesTable() throws SQLException {

            PreparedStatement createStatement = null;
            String sql = "update val_issues set PATCH_CREATION_INFO = ? where VAL_ISSUE_ID = ?";
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            createStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ...
    }
```

EDIT: I create a mocked Connection in my test class:

```
private Connection conn = mock(Connection.class);
```

Comment: You better create `Connection` object in the Main Class of your program.
In every Class' methods() where you wanna use it,`call that method of Main Class which would return an instance of the Connection Object`!

Comment: This method would still have to establish a connection, by calling a method like `getConnection()`. I am not quite sure what you are suggesting, or why that would help.

Comment: Actually,I didn't understand your statement as to what does `mocking` mean? Sorry,if you feel I am guilty for posting comment without knowing things! But,I thought that you might be requiring only a single Connection object everytime to connect to. Sorry Again for such mistake!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you unit test private methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250692/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440786/junit-java-testing-non-public-methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-proper-way-to-test-a-class-with-private-methods-using-junit

Answer (score 0):

You should get connection from a connection pool (C3P0 or Tomcat Connection Pool are good candidates), then you can mock the ConnectionPool.getConnection() method to return a connection mock.

Other than that look for @RunWith MockitoJUnitRunner examples to show how you can @InjectMocks into your test classes.  No shortcuts here - its easy enough when you know how but will take a bit of time to master.