# Accessing inner enum in another class for testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, enums

How do I access inner enum classes in another class? For example:

```
public class Foo {
    enum Bar {
        ONE, TWO, FOUR, EIGHT, SIXTEEN
    }

    // ...methods here
}
```

The class I am trying to access `Foo.Bar` in:

```
public class FooTest {
    private Foo f;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        f = new Foo();
    }

    public void testCase1() {
        assertEquals(Bar.ONE, f.climbUp());
    }
}
```

I've tried `Foo.Bar.ONE`, `Bar.ONE` as well as making a new variable using `Foo.class.getDeclaredField("Bar")` but none of these seem to be working. `getDeclaredClasses()` seems to get me `$Bar` but I can't access anything from there.

**Update:** I'm not allowed to modify the class `Foo`

Comment: Make Bar public:  `public static enum Bar`

Comment: What do you mean with "not working" (compile error? runtime error? test fails?) and what does this have to do with reflection?

Comment: If you need the enum to not be available from the outside world, but want it accessible for a test - the default level is `package-private`, so you could make the test in the same package.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440786/junit-java-testing-non-public-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to test it, but keep the enum in the default accessibility (`package-private`), which is implied by your inability to edit `Foo` and the title of the other class, then a common approach is to make the test in the same package.  Meaning it can access the items with `default` visibility ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)).

The test:

```
package com.scratch;

public class FooTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(Foo.Bar.ONE));
    }
}
```

The other source:

```
package com.scratch;

public class Foo {
    enum Bar {
        ONE, TWO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use reflection here. Just make the enum "static":

```
public class Foo {
    static enum Bar {
        ONE, TWO, FOUR, EIGHT, SIXTEEN
    }

    // ...methods here
}
```

Then you can access it thru Foo.Bar.ONE

Comment: Forgot to mention that I cannot modify `Foo`.

Comment: **Enums are implicitly static** (see the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#Enums)), it doesn't change if it can be accessed in this case or not.  The issue here is the [Access Modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)