# Access private enum in legacy code in

Tags: java, enums

I have legacy code where is private enum which I need to construct another type for acceptance testing, but I'm stuck because this enum is private and it is not part of any class, looks like following:

```
enum Element {
    ELEMENT1, ELEMENT2;

    public static Element[] values() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static Element valueOf(java.lang.String name) { /* compiled code */ }

    private Element() { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

is there a way how to use this enum, expose it from legacy code, or maybe way how to mock it?

Update:
I know I can read values enums by reflection, but I have another class which is public and I need to use enum value in its constructor, this class is in the same package like Element, its constructor is :

```
public class ElementProvider {
   public ElementProvider(string name, Element element){ /*compiled code*/ }
}
```

Comment: Is it private? Where is it defined? As per above code it's package default. [read more...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: @user3218114 Look likes package-private. Well, I think reflection is the only way here

Comment: Yes it's package-private, how can I reach enum which is not part of any class by reflection? Basically I know just namespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to test a class with private methods using JUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-proper-way-to-test-a-class-with-private-methods-using-junit)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497765/accessing-inner-enum-in-another-class-for-testing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way to do it could be to use `Class.forName` and load it using the package + name.

For example:

```
Class<?> enumElement = Class.forName("com.my.package.Element");
```

Then if everything is OK you will have the enum.

Then with `getEnumConstants` you can read all constants of the enum (*you can check if it's an enum using `isEnum` if needed*):

```
Object[] enumElements = elements.getEnumConstants();

for (Object obj : enumElements) {
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

You are forced to use `Object` since you don't know what type it will be (well, you know but you can't access it)

And use `enumElements[0]` to access `ELEMENT1` and so on.

---

About your updated question, that's the first thing that comes in my mind:

```
Class<?> enumElement = Class.forName("org.myname.test.Element");
Object[] enumElements = elements.getEnumConstants();

Object element1 = enumElements[0];

ElementProvider elementProvider = ElementProvider.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, enumElement).newInstance("Hello", element1);
```